# differences between PC and ARM port with freenext.launch

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS (Indigo) on both a regular PC and an ARM embedded board (i.MX6x SABRE-Lite).
Both run Ubuntu 14.04.

After launching freenect.launch on the PC almost 200 topics are created.

After launching it on the ARM-board only a few dozen topics are created.

I don't need all the extra topics, so its working fine for me, but my question is, where can I find the points where this differentiation is made.
In the ROS sources, or in libfreenect, or in the ROS infrastructure?

I can't find it, hopefully someone here knows it...

UPDATE: if I do `freenext_launch freenect.launch` then `rostopic list|fgrep camera|wc` yields 194.

Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236903/differences-between-pc-and-arm-port-with-freenext.launch/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-14**:
"200 topics": are you sure? That seems a bit excessive ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have additional image transport or depth image transport plugins installed on your PC that you don't have installed on ARM?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2016-06-15**:
Thanks Austin, I did have additional image transport plugins installed on the PC.
That answers my question.